# Matrix gives in Python other norm value than in Matlab

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix, normalization

My goal is to use the matrix defined below in Matlab in my Python code but apparently the objects don't have the same norm? Thus, I believe that I made a mistake.

```py
Tforward = np.array(np.mat('0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274; \
                   0.219417649252501   0.449283757993216   0.449283757993216   0.219417649252501  -0.219417649252501  -0.449283757993216  -0.449283757993216  -0.219417649252501; \
                   0.569359398342846   0.402347308162278  -0.402347308162278  -0.569359398342846  -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284  -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284; \
                  -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284  -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284   0.569359398342846   0.402347308162278  -0.402347308162278  -0.569359398342846; \
                   0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0; \
                   0                   0   0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547                   0                   0                   0                   0; \
                   0                   0                   0                   0   0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547                   0                   0; \
                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0   0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547'))

sum(Tforward**2,2)

>>> array([3.00428749, 2.99571251, 2.99571251, 3.00428749, 3.00428749,
       2.99571251, 2.99571251, 3.00428749])
```

```matlab
Tforward =  [ 0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274   0.353553390593274;
       0.219417649252501   0.449283757993216   0.449283757993216   0.219417649252501  -0.219417649252501  -0.449283757993216  -0.449283757993216  -0.219417649252501;
       0.569359398342846   0.402347308162278  -0.402347308162278  -0.569359398342846  -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284  -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284;
      -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284  -0.083506045090284   0.083506045090284   0.569359398342846   0.402347308162278  -0.402347308162278  -0.569359398342846;
       0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0;
                       0                   0   0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547                   0                   0                   0                   0;
                       0                   0                   0                   0   0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547                   0                   0;
                       0                   0                   0                   0                   0                   0   0.707106781186547  -0.707106781186547];   

sum(Tforward.^2,2)

>>> ans =

   1.00000
   1.00000
   1.00000
   1.00000
   1.00000
   1.00000
   1.00000
   1.00000
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Use `np.sum` with properly set `axis`parameter instead of `sum`.

Comment: @taha So, ```np.sqrt(np.sum(Tfor**2,axis=1))``` is the same as ```np.linalg(Tforward)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between MATLAB Sum and Python Sum is not the same thing. If you have MATRIX A, sum(A,2) in Matlab gives you the sum from the second column. However, in Python, sum(A,2) gives you the sum from of the list but also applies the number you entered into the list.

So in MATLAB you did sum(A(:,2)) while in Python you did sum(A+2). I believe Taha is correct in the comments that you want np.sum instead

Comment: In my matlab-code, ```Tforward``` is normalized by ```(Tforward' * diag(sqrt(1./sum(Tforward.^2,2))))';```. So in fact it is already normalized. But in Python I have ```np.linalg(Tforward)``` equals ```2.828```?

Comment: I don’t have time to test it out this morning but I think there’s an additional problem I missed in my original answer. You can’t do T**2 in python. I think you want np.pow(T,2)

Comment: ```np.sum(np.pow(Tfor,2),axis=1)``` and ```np.sum(Tfor**2,axis=1)``` both give me ```array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])```. Reiterating, I still don't see why ```np.linalg(Tforward)``` gives me something different.